# How to deal with scanner exception

Tags: java

Basically I am taking a string input that represents a file.  That file can contain integers, doubles or random strings.  I am trying to iterate through the file adding all the integers and then taking the average of all of them.  The issue I'm stuck on is when I get something other than an integer.  I don't know how I am supposed to catch and deal with the error and then iterate onto the next part of the file.  I can't use if statements and I'm thoroughly stuck.

```
 String storeVariables = null;
  FileReader fileReader;
  BufferedReader bufferedReader;
  Scanner scanner = null;
  int total = 0;
  int itterate = 0;


  try{
      fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader);

      while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
          total += scanner.nextInt();

          itterate++;
      }

  }
 catch(Exception e){


 }       

  return total/itterate;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner#nextInt` may throws

**InputMismatchException** - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
**NoSuchElementException** - if input is exhausted
**IllegalStateException** - if this scanner is closed

Try this -

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
   try{
          total += scanner.nextInt();
          itterate++;
   }catach(RuntimeException nfe){...}
}
```

Comment: ahh well done good sir